# Is the isomorphism class of a fixed cardinality a set?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Is the isomorphism class of a fixed cardinality a set(not a proper class)? Or a fixed ordinality for that matter?
By "isomorphism" I mean just bijection for cardinals and order preserving bijection for ordinals, in the category of sets.

Comment: Only if the cardinalty in question is zero.
Each set is an element of a set of given nonzero cardinality,
so the union of all sets of a given nonzero
cardinality is the universe.

Comment: See also [Class of sets of a given infinite cardinality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21973/class-of-sets-of-a-given-infinite-cardinality) at MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isomorphism classes of the set {} and the ordinal 0 are sets, each with a single element.

let $\kappa$ be an non-zero ordinal and $\alpha$ # $\beta$ be the [natural sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) of the ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Since the natural sum is the restriction of the addition of [surreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_numbers) to ordinals, and the surreal numbers are an [ordered field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field), the natural sum is cancellative and strictly increasing. Therefore, for any ordinal $\gamma$, the set {$\gamma$#0, $\gamma$#1, ... $\gamma$#$\kappa$} of ordinals that are the natural sum of $\gamma$ and an ordinal less than $\kappa$ is order-isomorphic to $\kappa$.  These sets are different for different values $\gamma$, so this provides a bijection between the ordinals and a subclass of the isomorphism class of $\kappa$.  If the isomorphism class of $\kappa$ was a set, this subclass would be a set and therefore the ordinals would also form a set.  The ordinals cannot form a set, therefore the isomorphism class of $\kappa$ does not form a set.

Assuming the axiom of choice, every set is well-orderable. Given a well-ordering of a set there is a bijection between the order-isomorphism class of that set and a subclass of it's isomorphism(bijection) class. if the set is non-empty, then since it's order-isomorphism class is not a set it's isomorphism class is not a set either.

This can also be proved without the axiom of choice. Suppose that a set x is bijectible
with  {y}$\sqcup$ z, where $\sqcup$ means disjoint union, for two sets y and z.  Then for any set w, x is bijectible with {w}$\sqcup$z , and since these sets are different for different values of w, this gives a bijection of the class of all sets with a subclass of the isomorphism class of x.  Since the class all sets cannot be a set, the isomorphism class of x cannot be a set. It remains to be shown that any non-empty set x is bijectible with {y}$\sqcup$z for two sets y and z. to see this, simply choose one element v from x (this does not require the axiom of choice, because we are only making one choice of one element from one set) and write x as the union of {v} and the set of other elements of x.  these two sets are disjoint, so the obvious surjection from their disjoint union to their union is a bijection. The union is x, so v and the set of other elements of x are the y and z we were looking for, respectively.

Comment: This sound very complicated to me.  Why mention surreal numbers?  
Given a nonempty set $X$, consider the class of all
sets of the form $X_y=\{(x,y):x\in X\}$, where $y$ is any set.  
Without AC there is a bijection between $X$ and $X_y$, by mapping each $x\in X$ to $(x,y)$.  Clearly the collection of all $X_y$
is a proper class.

Comment: Still, the mention to surreal numbers makes it more illuminating...

Comment: @DavidFernandezBreton, lol that made me laugh, bitime. (You're *are* being sarcastic, right?)

Comment: @user18921: Ok., maybe "illuminating" was not the word I should have used, but nevertheless I like the argument (even if unnecessarily complicated) because I like surreal numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the first part can be rephrased as: Is the system of all sets of a given cardinality a set or a proper class.
It is a proper class already for singletons: Just notice that $x\mapsto\{x\}$ is a bijection between all sets and all singletons.
Or, for a given cardinal $\varkappa$, you can use the bijection $x\mapsto \{x\}\times\varkappa$ between the class of all sets and a class consisting only of sets of cardinality $\varkappa$ (although not all of them).
If singletons (sets of cardinality $\varkappa$) formed a set, then (by axiom schema of replacement) the class of all sets would be a set too, a contradiction.

(By the way, this is pretty much along the same lines as what Robin Chapman and Stefan Geschke wrote in their comments.)

Comment: This comment might be slightly off-topic, but it explains why this question interested me. 
A natural possibility to define a cardinal number would be the class of all sets of the same cardinality. The problem is that this is a proper class. This problem can be resolved if we accept AC for classes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice or, as I learned while trying to find a reference for the original question, using Scott's trick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick
Forster's book referenced at wikipedia mentions answer to the original question in section 8.6.1.